# invalid conversion from const char* to int

Tags: c++, c++11

I have four files in c++

```
BankAccount.h
BankDatabase.h
Main.cpp
```

**BankAccount.h**

```
#include <string>
class BankAccount
{
    public:
        BankAccount(int accNumber,const std::string& accName);
        void setAccNumber(const int accNumber);
        int getAccNumber() const;
        void setAccName(const std::string& clientName);
        std::string getAccName() const ;
    protected:
        int mAccNumber;
        std::string mAccName;
};
BankAccount::BankAccount(const int accNumber,
        const std::string& accName):mAccNumber(accNumber),mAccName(accName){}
void BankAccount::setAccNumber(const int accNumber)
{
   mAccNumber = accNumber;     
}
void BankAccount::setAccName(const std::string& accName)
{
    mAccName = accName;
}
int BankAccount::getAccNumber() const 
{
    return mAccNumber;
}
std::string BankAccount::getAccName() const {
    return mAccName;
}
```

**BankDatabase.h**

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "BankAccount.h"
class BankDatabase
{
    public:
        BankDatabase();
        void addAccount(const BankAccount& acc);
        void deleteAccount(int accNumber);
        BankAccount& findAccount(int accNumber) 
            throw (std::out_of_range);
        BankAccount& findAccount(std::string& accName) 
            throw (std::out_of_range);
        void mergeDatabase(BankDatabase& db);
    protected:
        std::map<int,BankAccount> mAccounts;
};
BankDatabase::BankDatabase(){}
void BankDatabase::addAccount(const BankAccount& acc)
{
    std::pair<std::map<int,BankAccount>::iterator,bool> res =  
        mAccounts.insert(std::make_pair(acc.getAccNumber(),acc));
    if(!res.second)
        std::cout << "Account cannot be  added ";
}
void  BankDatabase::deleteAccount(int accNumber) 
{
    if( mAccounts.count(accNumber))
        mAccounts.erase(accNumber);
}
BankAccount& BankDatabase::findAccount(int accNumber)
    throw(std::out_of_range)
{
    auto iter =  mAccounts.find(accNumber);
    if(iter != mAccounts.end())
        return iter->second;
    throw std::out_of_range("No account number with this name ");
}
BankAccount& BankDatabase::findAccount(std::string& accName) 
    throw(std::out_of_range)
{
    for(auto& p : mAccounts) {
        if ( p.second.getAccName() == accName )
            return p.second;
    }
    throw std::out_of_range(" No account with this name ");
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BankDatabase.h"
int main()
{
    BankDatabase db;
    db.addAccount(BankAccount(1,"james"));
    db.addAccount(BankAccount(2,"johnson"));
    db.addAccount(BankAccount(3,"kamal"));
    db.addAccount(BankAccount(4,"appu"));
    // find account name based on account number
    std::cout << db.findAccount(1).getAccName();
    // find account number based on account name
    std::cout << db.findAccount("james");
    // delete an account
    db.deleteAccount(db.findAccount("james").getAccNumber());
    // find the account
    std::cout << db.findAccount("james");
    //Merge database
    db.mergeDatabase(db);
    return 0;
}
```

At the statement `std::cout << db.findAccount("james");` I got an error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int'

But I defined `findAccount(int)` and `findAccount(string)` in `BankDatabase.h`

Can someone help in this issue?

Comment: You didn't define `findAccount(string)`, your function is `findAccount(string&)`. Read the entire error message, your compiler should tell you why each `findAccount` member function is not viable as currently written. I don't see any `operator<<(ostream&, BackAccount)` definitions either, so you have more problems than the one you're asking about.

Comment: Yes, there is no known conversion from a string literal to a `std::string&`. However you can convert a string literal to a `const std::string&` or a `std::string`. Also, when you run in such an error, try to reproduce that error with a smaller code, that helps understanding the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
BankAccount& findAccount(std::string& accName)
```

use

```
BankAccount& findAccount(std::string const& accName)
```

When the function is called with `"james"`, that cannot be converted to a `std::string&` but it can be converted to a temporary `std::string`, which can be used as an argument when the argument type is `std::string const&`.

Also,

```
std::cout << db.findAccount(std::string("james"));
```

is a problem since there is no `operator<<()` defined between `std::ostream` and `BankAccount`.

Answer (score 1):

You defined two overloads for findAccount, one taking an int and another one taking a std::string reference. 
The argument you tried to call it with is not a std::string, but a c-string, that is a const char*. The compiler now has two options:

In order to call the int version a conversion from const char* to int would be needed(this is the error you see).

In order to call the string version a temporary std::string would have to be created. After this, a non-const reference to a temporary would have to be formed(which is not allowed and the error you either dont see or did not show in your question).

Since you do not seem to change the string a simple fix of this problem would be to take a const std::string& instead. Your code has some other problems, too.